# Reliable alternatives to Skype Numbers / Local Phone for Android, for receiving calls to an overseas landline number?

Tags: android, phone, voip

I'm looking for an Android app that:

- Can receive via the internet calls made to a registered landline number (specifically, a UK number). I don't mind how this is implemented (VOIP, SIP, etc?) and I don't mind paying for such a number.
- **Reliably** notifies me of incoming calls, and missed calls, any time I have a data connection.

Reliability of notifications is my #1 criteria for this app, and my problem with the options I've found so far (see below).

---

I set up a **[Skype number](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.localphone.localphoneapp&hl=en)** so that overseas clients could call me as easily as calling a local landline. Unfortunately, [a major bug with Skype for Android that has gone unfixed for a year and has no workaround](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128732/how-to-make-skype-always-active-reliably-receiving-and-notifying-about-calls-in) makes Skype for Android unsuitable for this purpose.

Despite claiming to run in the background, it doesn't notify you of incoming calls unless you're sat with the app window open and the screen on, constantly refreshing the screen. Even worse, it doesn't notify of missed calls until you next open the app window. I've had major problems where a client has tried to call me about some urgent matter, and I've not even known that they called until weeks later.

There are literally hundreds of comments, questions and bug reports about this on Skype's forum ([one example among many](http://community.skype.com/t5/Android/No-incoming-call-and-chat-notification-on-Android-KitKat/td-p/3192984)) with no useful response from Skype.

[image]

---

There's a [similar discussion on the Skype forum](http://community.skype.com/t5/Skype-Number/Skype-Number-alternative-service/td-p/4102006) where someone recommends the app **[Local Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.localphone.localphoneapp&hl=en)** which has an [Incoming Number service](https://www.localphone.com/services/incoming_numbers). This sounds like a good fit - however, I've not (yet) been able to get it to work and it has some pretty poor reviews. I'm not sure if it's fundamentally not functional or if there's some step in the setup that both me and these reviewers are getting wrong.

[image]

---

To be clear, the #1 thing I'm looking for is **reliability**:

- If someone calls my overseas number, I want my Android phone to ring any time I have a data connection. **Every time** so long as I have a data connection and haven't purposefully logged out, like Whatsapp calls.
- If I miss a call, I want a notification to appear as soon as I next have a data connection, that tells me who called and when.
- Ideally, it'd be nice to also be able to pay to make outgoing calls to landlines and mobiles at a rate similar to the local rate using the app, but this is very much secondary (this is the one thing Skype for Android can actually reliably do)

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing those additional details! I've integrated them with your question (our edits crossed, I've fixed that) and will cleaup comments now. As initially stated, you can check with [several SIP clients here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_cheapcall#group_72) (some having a service attached which might have your re-routing integrated). Good luck!

Comment: Your edit came at the same time as mine - I've redone my edit which hopefully makes the core of the question clearer

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to have calls received on a landline? Nothing will ever be as reliable as a landline connected to the PSTN, so do that if possible

Comment: No, I'm trying to "receive via the internet calls made to a registered landline number". I'm in a country with very little landline infrastructure, but good 3G networks. I want an app that receives voice data via the internet, my requirements are that it has reliable notifications, and that it integrates with a service similar to Local Phone or Skype Numbers that register a landline then direct calls to that number via the internet.

Comment: Did you find a good alternative?
I have the exact same issues with my Skype number where it seems to "hibernate" and the phone doesn't ring or tell me I have missed a call until I physically refresh the phone screen or open the app......even though I am permanently logged in and the phone is on.

Comment: @MarkS No, not really, other than Localphone described above. More recently I've received a few calls to the skype number when my phone has been in my pocket, but basically my workaround is unfortunately to not rely on skype. I'd suggest contacting Skype support - several months ago there did appear to be someone working on this so at the very least they should give you a status update (though they've failed to fix it for three years now...)

Comment: linked posts [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128732/how-to-make-skype-always-active-reliably-receiving-and-notifying-about-calls-in) and [2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_prevandroms-skype_callms-skype_audioms/not-getting-skype-call-notifications-on-android/740014ea-69ce-4ce2-ac99-3b5e8e3ee359)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up one of the UK SIP-providers accounts which provide free [DID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_inward_dial)s. For example, [Sticky Numbers](https://www.stickynumber.com/) provide toll-free UK-numbers (+4470) for free. However, they are expensive for the caller, not for you :)

After sign up, in the account dashboard you can set up forwarding to their (or your custom) SIP trunk, and then just add this number to your Android SIP client. This will be somewhat similar to what you want: you will be notified about the calls and can respond to them. Also, in the Sticky account there is primitive stats panel, which help you to track things when you are offline.